# Better way to use html templete with json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am getting json response from my server.
I am getting detail of user like school(name,id),major subject(name,id),start ,end etc.

I want to show this is appropriate text fields inside a form where user can edit this and after editing user should submit it again to server.
I am embadding fetched json code with html code inside the jquery.
I am finding it very difficult to manage html inside jquery is there any better way to this with following code.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.edit-edu', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).parents('.row').attr('id');
  var id1 = id.split('-');
  $.post("SingleEdu", {id: id1[1]}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $.each(data.educationList, function(key, value) {
      $('#' + id).replaceWith('<div id="addNewEdu" class="addorEdit">'
      + '<legend>Edit education details</legend>'
      + '<form action="UpdateEducation" id="UpdateEducation" cssClass="form-horizontal">'
      + '<div class="form-group">'
      + '<div class="col-md-2">'
      + '<label>School/College</label>'
      + '</div>'
      + '<div class="col-md-6">'
      + ' <textfield name="ed.pageBySchoolPid.name" value="' + value.pageBySchoolPid.name + '" id="school2" label="School/College" placeholder="College or School Name" cssClass="form-control">'                                        + '</textfield>'
      + '<input type="hidden" name="ed.pageBySchoolPid.id" value="' + value.pageBySchoolPid.id + '" id="schoolId2" label="School/College" cssClass="form-control">'
      + '</hidden>'
      + '</div>'
      + '</div>'
      + '<div class="form-group">'
      + '<div class="col-md-2">'
      + '<label>Major</label>'
      + '</div>'
      + '<div class="col-md-6">'
      + '<input type="text" name="ed.pageByMajorPid.name" value="' + value.pageByMajorPid.name + '" id="major1" label="Class" placeholder="Major Subject" cssClass="form-control">'
      + '<input type="hidden" name="ed.pageByMajorPid.id" value="' + value.pageByMajorPid.id + '" id="majorId1" label="Class" cssClass="form-control">'
      + '</div>'
      + '</div>'
      + '<div class="form-group">'
      + '<div class="col-md-2">'
      + '<label>Start</label>'
      + '</div>'
      + '<div class="col-md-6">'
      + '<input type="text"  name="ed.start"  value="' + value.start + '" id="sstart1" label="From" placeholder="eg. Start: July 2007" cssClass="form-control">'
      + '</div>'
      + '</div>'
      + '<div class="form-group">'
      + '<div class="col-md-2">'
      + '<label>End</label>'
      + '</div>'
      + '<div class="col-md-6">'
      + '<input type="text" name="ed.end" value="' + value.end + '" id="send1" label="To"  placeholder="eg. End : May 2011 or Till" cssClass="form-control">'
      + '</div>'
      + '</div>'
      + '<div class="form-group">'
      + '<div class="col-md-2">'
      + '<label>Visibility</label>'
      + ' </div>'
      + '<div class="col-md-6">'
      + '<select label="Visibility" name="ed.visibility"  value="' + value.visibility + '" id="svisibility1" value="public" cssClass="form-control">'
      + '<option>Public</option>'
      + '<option>Friends</option>'
      + '<option>Me</option>'
      + '</select>'
      + '</div>'
      + '</div>'
      + '<div class="form-group">'
      + '<div class="col-md-2">'
      + '<label class="sr-only">Submit</label>'
      + '</div>'
      + '<div class="col-md-6">'
      + '<input type="submit" value="add" id="submit_education" cssClass="btn btn-sm btn-success"/>'
      + '</div>'
      + '</div>'
      + '</form>')
    });
   });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></script>




 <div class="row" id="edu-56">
   <div>Specialization</div>
    <div>School</div>
    <div>start &nbsp; end</div>
   
     <i class="fa fa-edit edit-edu">edit</i>
     <i class="fa fa-times delete-edu"></i>
   </div>
```

Comment: When I need html on the clientside, I create html with templates on the serversite. If you do not want that, you could include most of your html in the html file and hide it via css, then just replace the values and show the html by setting css to show the html via js.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your code inside another `.html` file and pull it in using another AJAX call:

```
var FormHTML = '';
$.get('form.html', function(data) {
    FormHTML = data;
});
```

Then to get your values in you can set up your input HTML with something that can be easily replaced out. I've just wrapped the object name in between some `#`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ed.pageByMajorPid.id" value="##pageByMajorPid.id##" id="majorId1" label="Class" cssClass="form-control">
```

Then to replace out these values with your actual values, just do a loop:

```
for (var name in value) {
    if (typeof value[name] != 'object') { // If not an object, replace the value
        formHTML = formHTML.replace('##' + name + '##', value[name])
    } else { // Else if it is an object, loop through it
        for (var name2 in value[name]) {
            formHTML = formHTML.replace('##' + name + '.' + name2 + '##', value[name][name2])
        }
    }
}
$('#' + id).replaceWith(formHTML);
```

Hope that works for you, let me know :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use template engine like Mustache https://mustache.github.io/